# How to avoid $compile:tpload errors on 401 status code response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

We are developing a Single Page Application with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC Json Rest API.

When an unauthenticated client tries to navigate to a private route (Ex: */Foo/Home/Template*) to get a template, it gets a 401 response from the Web API and our AngularJS app automatically redirects it to the login page.

We are handling the 401 with [$http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) with something like this:

```
if (response.status === 401) { 
        $location.path(routeToLogin);
        return $q.reject(response);
}
```

Entering the correct credentials allows the client to get the template.

Everything is working perfectly except for one detail; the Javascript console reports this error:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$compile/tpload?p0=%Foo%2FHome%2FTemplate%2F
```

[AngularJs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload) states this:

> **Description**
>
> This error occurs when $compile attempts to fetch a template from some
>   URL, and the request fails.

In our AngularJs app the request fails but it is by design because the resource is there but it cannot be accessed (401).

Should I move on and accept this kind of error on console or is it possible to mute or shield it in some way?

**EDIT:**

I have debugged the angular source a little bit and I found what part of the code is raising the exception.
Since we are using `TemplateUrl` to declare our templates, we are indirectly using the function `compileTemplateUrl` that makes this call:

```
$templateRequest($sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(templateUrl))
```

this leaves the second parameter (`ignoreRequestError`) of `templateRequest` undefined.

> **ignoreRequestError(optional)boolean**
>
> Whether or not to ignore the exception when the request fails or the
>   template is empty

When our http interceptor, handling the 401 status code, rejects the promise, the $http.get inside the `$TemplateRequestProvider` fails and calls this function:

```
 function handleError() {
        self.totalPendingRequests--;
        if (!ignoreRequestError) {
          throw $compileMinErr('tpload', 'Failed to load template: {0}', tpl);
        }
        return $q.reject();
      }
```

I believe we can't do anything to prevent the error on console as `TemplateUrl` does not allow to set the `ignoreRequestError` flag to false.

I've tried to bypass the reject in case of 401 status code; this fixes the error on console but sadly it has a side effect: an empty template is wrongly cached into the `TemplateCache` causing othe problems.

Comment: Would modifying whatever is causing that template to load be an option? You could try to add the template to the `$templateCache` yourself and swallow the error accordingly.

Comment: It's the homepage template and it has to be loaded.

Comment: Are you using ui-bootstrap ?????

Comment: @vcrzy yes, we are using angular ui-bootstrap.

Comment: The router should prevent that route from being taken in the first place.

Comment: Why are you allowing that route to get executed if user does not have permission for it, so you need to check the permissions on client side as well and not only on server side.

Comment: @harish simply because client is agnostic from the logic of the server; it does not know how the server works and which resources requires authentication and which not.

Comment: you can shield yourself from such errors given that you are throwing custom exception from server which you can identify on client...

Comment: In our Http interceptor we are handling the 401 in `ResponseError`, changing the location to the login page and returning the reject promise.

Comment: @systempuntoout what do you mean when you say the homepage template has to be loaded? If it gives a 401, there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: Is downgrading angular an option? before it would have the ignoreErrors set to true, they changed it somewhere in 1.3 iirc.

Comment: @PiniH no, it is not an option but thanks to have pointed out that it changed in 1.3 . I thought the problem started to raise when we switched from anonymous template to private template; most likely it was when we switched to 1.3. .

Comment: @JonathanAmend but it could return a 200 and client does not know it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some thinking I remembered about decorating in Angular, it solved this problem perfectly:

```
app.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$templateRequest', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {

    var fn = $delegate;

    $delegate = function(tpl) {

      for (var key in fn) {
        $delegate[key] = fn[key];
      }

      return fn.apply(this, [tpl, true]);
    };

    return $delegate;
  }]);
}]);
```

Comment: it looks like an interesting approach, I will take a look at it.

Comment: This breaks animation for my app. Commenting this decoraator out lets ngMaterial (thus ngAnimate) render correct classes for animation. Any ideas why?

Comment: It could be that they added some new functions to the template request, did you try to debug and see what the original was? if there are any more methods you should override/retarget them to the new decorator.

Comment: 'handleRequestFn.totalPendingRequests = 0;'
I think ngAnimate waits for totalPendingRequests to hit 0, but because of the wrapping this gets imbalanced. you can try to read the $templateRequest code, it's not long and figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: I'm getting errors after compile with this function. Any ideas? Need I inject $templateRequest ?

Comment: Found it! Edited the answer to inject $delegate.

Comment: Now I'm having issues with ng-animate using this code, any clues?

Comment: Worked like a charm, I had to place the config in multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to intercept the call for the template by status and url.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qTpo4Ms7EAbO5a5ZVpuK?p=preview)**

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {

  var interceptor = function($location, $log, $q) {

      function success(response) {
        // The response if complete
        $log.info(response);
        return response;
      }

      function error(response) {
        // The request if errors
        $log.error(response);
        return $q.reject(response);
      }

      return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
      }
    }

  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);

});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. We are already using Http interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have two options:

### **Option A)**

go with the interceptors. However, to eliminate the compile you need to return success status code inside response error (BAD) OR redirect to the login page inside the interceptor (Good):

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService', function () {

    var interceptor = {};

    interceptor.responseError = function (rejection) {

        if (rejection.status === 401 && rejection.config.url === "home template url") {

            //BAD IDEA
            //console.log("faking home template");
            //rejection.status = 200;
            //rejection.data = "<h1>should log in to the application first</h1>";

            //GOOD IDEA
            window.location = "/login.html";
        }

        return rejection;
    }


    return interceptor;
});
```

and on app config:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
}
```

### **Option b)**

make the home template public. After all it should be just html mark-up, without any sensible information.

this solution is clean...and perhaps is also possible.

Comment: I believe the only working solution could be the option b but we are trying to avoid the anonymous access even for the html markup.

Comment: Iam using [silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) for my scala client backend  to protect any html markup using secured and user aware actions. Maybe there is something similar for your ASP.NET "backend".